# vue-cli loader not working with default init for webpack-simple

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server

I am learning Vue.JS. I installed the cli and created a project:

```
$ npm install -g vue-cli
$ vue init webpack-simple vue-example
$ cd vue-example
$ npm install
$ npm run dev  # this is where problem starts!
```

I get this error message:

```
> vue-example@1.0.0 dev /Users/me/Code/vue/vue-example
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /dist/
404s will fallback to /index.html
loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
Hash: adf2dedbe76c7658d182
Version: webpack 2.3.1
Time: 7592ms
                                    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
logo.png?82b9c7a5a3f405032b1db71a25f67021  6.85 kB          [emitted]
                                 build.js  1.59 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
chunk    {0} build.js (main) 565 kB [entry] [rendered]
   [22] ./~/vue/dist/vue.esm.js 244 kB {0} [built]
   [38] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
   [39] ./src/main.js 134 bytes {0} [built]
   [40] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 5.44 kB {0} [built]
   [41] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.57 kB {0} [built]
   [42] ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue 188 bytes {0} [built]
   [44] ./src/App.vue 1.59 kB {0} [built]
   [50] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.6 kB {0} [built]
   [51] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 856 bytes {0} [built]
   [56] (webpack)-dev-server/~/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js 244 bytes {0} [built]
   [87] (webpack)-dev-server/~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
   [88] (webpack)-dev-server/~/strip-ansi/~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
   [90] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.02 kB {0} [built]
   [96] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
   [98] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
     + 84 hidden modules

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"id":"data-v-32781a4c","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at loadLoader (/Users/me/Code/vue/vue-example/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/Users/me/Code/vue/vue-example/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/Users/me/Code/vue/vue-example/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
 @ ./~/vue-loader/~/vue-style-loader!./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"id":"data-v-32781a4c","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 4:14-272 13:3-17:5 14:22-280
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I tried this with both vue-cli version 2.8.1 (latest) and an earlier one (2.5.0) with no luck.

Anyone know how to fix this? Seems like the defaults should work out of the box...

I'm all new to Vue / webpack so go easy on me.

Comment: Looks like a CSS syntax issue.

Comment: I found the github repo and followed the instructions and it worked for me.  Did you already have npm or was that a new install?  Did you see any errors when you ran npm install?  I have at times had to run npm install twice in order to fix errors.  You might try that.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I am using Windows 10.  
It isn't a css issue, despite the message.  It happens even if you just put a blank <style></style> tag in your .vue.
My hunch is that it is something in my global npm packages that is the culprit.  I am going to find a VM and do a test.

Comment: Same issue on AWS Linux.

Comment: Yep, I needed to get newest version of node & npm. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I resolved this was to:

- npm cache clean
- npm update -g
- reinstalled node.js (https://nodejs.org/en/download/)  -  v6.10.1

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: My brew version was way outdated. So installer from node.js website and redoing `npm install` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Which version is your node.
Mine is v7.1.0

you may need

```
npm cache clean
npm update -g
```